# Testing tool for javaScript, CSS , HTML , jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome. I have several .js , .css , .html files in my project and I'm using notepad++ for coding. But i have to do some testing before each phase ends. Is there any standard way to do testing for them. (eg : in java we have JUnit, likewise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Javascript - http://www.jslint.com/, http://sinonjs.org,
   http://qunitjs.com/ to name a few
2. CSS Use http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
3. HTML - http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single framework that I know of but you can use JSLint for Javascript or other frameworks as Raoul has mentioned. For css and html use the wc3 validators.
http://validator.w3.org/ for html and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ for css

Answer (score 1):

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/)
is my preferred testing framework for Javascript.